# Why am I randomly loosing focus from the active window in KDE?

Tags: kde, focus

Some months ago, I noticed that at random times the `krunner` pop-up (`KDE` run-command utility) appeared and stile focus from the active window. While `krunner` has stopped popping-up, I still loose focus randomly. As I write this, I am losing focus from the edit field ever 7/8 seconds.

I have seen some forums posts discussing this:

- ["it drives me crazy"](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/499547-13-1-KDE-window-focus-repeatedly-quot-stolen-quot)
- ["This is an difficult bug"](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155951)

I think that now the focus is stolen by the panel/s. The panel/s don't have input fields so it's hard to figure out where the focus goes. What happens is that the panel impose itself on the desktop and steals the focus around every 7/8 seconds as mentioned above.

Comment: i have the same issue? can any one help